# Rendering a template received via AJAX in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm loading an HTML template via AJAX from within an angularjs controller and would like to use it to render a collection of JSON objects I'm also loading via AJAX. How can I get angularjs to render my template string as a collection and insert it into the DOM?

Comment: did you try any? please, post what you did so far

Comment: likely easier to use a directive....  `templateURL` is part of directive object

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for ngBindTemplate: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindTemplate

Pass the template text retrieved from the first AJAX call in as the value for ngBindTemplate, and then make sure the JSON from the second call is put into the right place in the controller $scope to resolve the references in the template.